# Lateinit Variable getting UninitializedPropertyAccessException though initialized at onCreateView

Tags: android, kotlin

Using Binding in kotlin and  declared it as lateinit var. Initialized the value in on Crate view but still getting Uninitialized Property Access Exception for some devices. Not getting what i did wrong here.

```
class DemoFragment: Fragment(), GenericListItemPickerBottomSheet.CallBack {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "DemoFragment"
    }

    lateinit var binding: FragmentDemoBinding
    var callback: CompressParameterChangeCallback? = null
    var width: Int = 1080
    var height: Int = 720
    var oWidth: Int = 1080
    var oHeight: Int = 720
    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View {
        binding = FragmentDemoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.widthField.setText(width.toString())
        binding.heightField.setText(height.toString())
        return binding.root
    }
```

The Exception I am getting :

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
```

Comment: post the exception so people can analyse the issue better

Comment: I don’t see any problems in this code. Can you show the entire class?